# Sign column font is cut off

Tags: neovim, macos, font, neovim-qt, signs

I have an issue where the signs in my sign column are cut off in the middle (screenshot below).

[image]

Changing the Guifont or the font size doesn't seem to matter. It looks fine in terminal neovim.

I am using neovim 0.1.5 and neovim-qt on macOS 10.10.5.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a bug in neovim-qt (or neovim)? I would recommend reporting it on the neovim-qt issue tracker. You'll probably get a better response there.

Comment: Reported at: https://github.com/equalsraf/neovim-qt/issues/195